# Recieve the first name of a user when they log in

Tags: php

I have implemented a basic and simple login method from using [this website](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html). I can log in successfully, but I want to retrieve the first name of the member who signs into the website to store it into a `$_SESSION` object.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$myemail' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
     //$_SESSION[];
    //  header("Location:http://localhost/website/test.php");
     }
     else 
         echo "Wrong Username or Password";
```

[image: Reference to the table]

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated and insecure. Use PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @rar hello, I'm aware of this. But for my coursework, my tutor said he doesn't mind 'MySQL_' functions for now, next coursework, we will be using 'MySQLi' I need to use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want to do ?

```
if($count==1)
{        
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

     session_start();
     $_SESSION['first_name'] =  $row['firstname'];

     header("Location:http://localhost/website/test.php");
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you very much! It's a shame people are giving bad feedback for the use of 'MySQL_'.

Comment: @Moynul , Glad to help . times are changing bro , every day there are better thing coming :) We have to accept them right :)

Comment: I understand too, and I'll be changing my methods too, but for now my teacher wants me to use the old functions.

Comment: Yes , start with MySQL , learn the concepts . then move to a better one , thats all right , i wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 1):

`email` field must contain unique entries.

See, both of the `id-4` & `id-4` rows contain exact same data. 
But as for your answer,

```
if($count==1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$f_name = $row['firstname'];
}
```

Now, if `email=cf@hotmail.com` and `password=g` then your query will fail, because `$count` will not be `1`. So a valid user will also see a login fail message.

Comment: Works well. Does the job!

Comment: P.S - I understand the 'count == 1' code. The other entries have been dropped. I am using 'test' as a 'test' account.